# postgresql pg_database_size throwing exception on random times

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-functions

We are using Azure database for PostgreSQL ( Service ) for creating DB for each user when user register to the application ( less than 25 users databases right now ).

For reporting purpose we need information which each user's DB size.
To retrieve database size we have a Postgres function which fires the following query

```
SELECT pg_database.datname , pg_database_size(pg_database.datname) FROM 
pg_database
```

We execute this function every hour throw azure function but at random time Postgres throw exceptions

```
Exception: Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 58P01: could not read directory "base/16452": No such file or directory at...
```

Exception remain same at most of the time with different directory or file location

Sometimes it also throws the exception

```
Exception: Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the solution at the MSDN forums [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1621e397-6959-4120-b53a-19f3f6431f1d/azure-function-throw-exception-random-time-while-executing-postgresql-function-to-calculate-db-size?forum=AzureFunctions).